# Issue with linux "adb push" command, "No such file or directory" error

Tags: android, ubuntu, push, adb, motorola

I am trying to develop a simple pygame with Ubuntu Linux 11.10 for my Motorola android phone. I am having trouble getting the "adb push" command to work. I get an `failed to copy 'foo.txt' to '/media/MOT': No such file or directory` error message. What am I doing wrong?

**Here is what I tried so far:**

The phone's SD card is mounted at /media/MOT/ and I am able to ls, create a folder and delete a folder in it.

```
     user@linuxlappy:~$ 
     user@linuxlappy:~$ cd /media/MOT/
     user@linuxlappy:/media/MOT$ ls
     Android  burstlyImageCache  burstlyVideoCache  data  DCIM  download  gstomperdemo  LOST.DIR  slacker  temp.apk
     user@linuxlappy:/media/MOT$ mkdir writetest
     user@linuxlappy:/media/MOT$ rmdir writetest/
```

The file that I am trying to copy is foo.txt in my /home/user/ directory

```
     user@linuxlappy:/media/MOT$ cd /home/user/
     user@linuxlappy:~$ ls foo.*
     foo.txt  foo.txt~
```

I enabled USB debugging on the phone with:
         Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging.

I believe I have adb installed correctly, I am able to list the phone with adb devices.

```
     user@linuxlappy:~$ adb devices
     List of devices attached 
     0910E8201700B017   device
```

When I try to push a simple text file to the SD card I get this error message.

```
     user@linuxlappy:~$ adb push foo.txt /media/MOT
     failed to copy 'foo.txt' to '/media/MOT': No such file or directory
     user@linuxlappy:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

> The phone's SD card is mounted at /media/MOT/

Based on your terminal output, it is mounted *on your desktop Linux environment* as `/media/MOT`. In which case, to copy files to it, you use `cp`.

Using `adb push`, you need to use the path where the external storage resides *on the phone*. A common spot is `/mnt/sdcard/`, though it may vary. Also, bear in mind that, depending on your phone, external storage may not be available while you have it mounted as a volume on your desktop Linux environment.

Comment: Does "cp" and "adb push" do the exact same thing?

Comment: @bgryderclock: Well, their net results are the same thing. However, they do not "do the exact same thing" any more than transferring a file via the Internet is "the exact same thing" as transferring a file via an old-time floppy disk. `cp` says "copy files between locations in mounted partitions". `adb push` says "copy files between the host machine and an attached device/emulator". `adb push` is closer in spirit to `scp`, which copies a file between your machine and another one over the Internet.http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles